# How to use a CTE in TVF or SP?

Tags: sql-server

This is my attendance table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StaffAttendance](
    [StaffId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__StaffAtten__Date__6CA31EA0]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [AttendanceStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AttendanceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__StaffAtt__8B69261DC5CF4AF2] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [AttendanceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UNIQ_staffDates] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [StaffId] ASC,
    [Date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StaffAttendance]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__StaffAtte__Atten__6E8B6712] FOREIGN KEY([AttendanceStatusId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AttendanceStatus] ([AttendanceStatusId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StaffAttendance] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__StaffAtte__Atten__6E8B6712]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StaffAttendance]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__StaffAtte__Staff__6D9742D9] FOREIGN KEY([StaffId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Staff] ([StaffId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StaffAttendance] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__StaffAtte__Staff__6D9742D9]
GO
```

And this query

```
SELECT [StaffId],
       [Date],
       [AttendanceStatusId]
  FROM [idiot].[dbo].[StaffAttendance]
```

gets me this result. Simple daily attendance recording.

[image: Simple attendance recording]

For reporting purpose, I have created this SP.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
@StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
        StaffAttendance.StaffId,
        DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS [ForMonth],
        (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
        SUM(StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked
        FROM StaffAttendance 
        WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId = 1 GROUP BY StaffAttendance.StaffId
END
GO
```

which ignores all Sunday(s) and gets total attendance between 2 dates. If I execute it,

```
EXEC [dbo].[spGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
  @StartDate = '2016-10-01', @EndDate = '2016-10-31'
```

this is what it conceives

[image: SP result]

Now what I want to do is simply give a varchar type as month name instead of date type for input. Like 'October' instead of [@StartDate = '2016-10-01', @EndDate = '2016-10-31'] so it gets start and end date on its own and give me my reporting output (2nd image)

I got help for getting start and end dates of a month by month name. This  is how its being done.

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(9) = 'october';

WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS StartDate,
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) AS EndDate
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month
```

And it does get me this

[image]

But I have no idea how to embed this CTE in my SP so that all I have to do is input month name - no date, no month number - just month name and my SP returns me the same result. I have been trying to do it for like 3 to 4 hours now, but this is huge for me and I lose focus. Any/all help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the CTE in the procedure as follows.  If you don't put the `;` in front of the CTE you will get this message.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllStaffCollectiveAttendanceByMonth]
@Month nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN

Declare @StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE

;WITH CteMonths(n, m) AS(
    SELECT 1, 'January' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'February' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'March' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'April' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'May' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 'June' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 'July' UNION ALL
    SELECT 8, 'August' UNION ALL
    SELECT 9, 'September' UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'October' UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, 'November' UNION ALL
    SELECT 12, 'December'
  )
SELECT @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, n - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 
@EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
FROM CteMonths
WHERE m = @month

SELECT
    StaffAttendance.StaffId,
    DATENAME(MONTH, @StartDate) AS [ForMonth],
    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalWorkingDays,
    SUM(StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId) AS TotalDaysWorked
    FROM StaffAttendance 
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND StaffAttendance.AttendanceStatusId = 1 GROUP BY StaffAttendance.StaffId
END
GO
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Can't believe it was just that.